# Deploying Django app, how to get South to work?

Tags: django, django-south

I am getting the following error in my error logs:
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named south

I did "easy_install South" to install South on my server, but I still get the error.

South is listed under INSTALLED_APPS of my settings.py as just 'south'. I think that it is not able to find 'south'. How do I figure out the location of where 'south' is installed and give my settings.py the full path?

I think that my python path in httpd.conf is not including the path where south is. How do I find out where south is located?

Comment: How do you deploy the Django app - mod_wsgi? Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: I'm using mod_wsgi, no virtualenv

Comment: Then debug `sys.path` using a WSGI script (something like [this](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use) but output `sys.path`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out where south is installed you could search your disk for south.

With Linux you could do this a few ways, you could use find or locate (make sure your locate databases is up to date) . On Windows you can use the windows file search. On Mac you can use spotlight.

Since you are not using virtualenv, then the files are most likely installed in a site-packages directory, and I'm pretty sure, but I could be wrong, the site-packages are normally on the sys path.

If you have more then one version of python installed on your machine, it might be possible, that you installed into one version and then are running mod_wsgi using a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you are using a virtual environment like pinax you have to install it in your virtual environment and not your computer. So you would first get the environment going:
 - `annasob$ source pinax-env/bin/activate`
and then do: 
 - `(pinax-env)annasob$ sudo pip install south`